# React Native error, undefined is not an object (evaluating _reactNativeLocalize.default) react-native-localize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, node-modules, react-native-ios

[Error on IOS sim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciEpw.png)

Imported a colleagues project which had an older version of react-native-localize (previously known as 'languages') I even had to change the imports of i18 to react-native-localize manually. Perhaps the import of an app with an old lib is whats causing this...

But im unsure of it. Couldnt find a good solution to this problem. Run npm install, resetted caches, restarted MAC, pod install, linking and unlinking... Problem persists, can anyone help?

Comment: which version  react-native-localize   you are using ?

Comment: Does the error disappear when you open the debugger ?

Comment: The react-native-localize is version 1.3.2. When I open the console the error changes from "undefined (evaluating _reactNativeLocalize.default.t)" to "undefined (cannot read property 't' of undefined)", and a new error I hadnt seen until now: 
Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
The other error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 't' of undefined
I really dont know where to start...